# Is renaming Google Drive files with coding possible?

Tags: encoding, google-drive-api

I want to rename quite a lot of files on my Google Drive.

I recently realized you could do this on a linux computer by using various commands in the command line. Is there a similar way this works for Google Drive?

How would I go about writing a script to do what I want? And in what language? (Bearing in mind I am a complete beginner in coding).

Thanks!

Comment: please do a minimal google search first for the google drive api.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Google Apps Script - Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/#classes). As per it's description in docs:

> This service allows scripts to create, **find, and modify files** and folders **in Google Drive**.

What you could do is like use the [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) to go over the files (`next()`) then use [File.setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename) on each File. Drive Service also has an API with regards to [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)s if you need them.

Hope this helps. Happy coding. :)